# Question concerning Zener diodes

Tags: zener

This is a general, hypothetical question concerning power dissipation and zener diodes. It's hypothetical in the sense that I don't have the question in front of me and I don't have any further information other than what follows. Say I have a DC source with a sinusoidal ripple, connected to a zener diode with a resistor; there's no load. What would be the average power dissipated in this circuit?

Comment: No load, as in open circuit? If that is the case, the answer is 0W (zero watts).

Comment: It depends.  Is the Zener forward or reversed biased? Is it avalanching at any time during operation?  If not, what's its leakage current?

Comment: I don't think the circuit is open as otherwise it would indeed be too easy and straightforward. Is there a way to connect a zener diode to a transistor and the two to a DC source+sinusoidal ripple so that the average power dissipated would be other than null?

Comment: In general, what would be the correct way to calculate the average power dissipated for a DC source with a sinusoidal ripple?

Comment: @peripatein, Power is always I*V. You can work it out from there. Or, if you want our help, **include a schematic** so we know what circuit your asking about and can address the specifics of that circuit.

Comment: @Dave_Tweed ineptly deleted my correct answer. All voltage sources and Zeners have a series impedance, the sum of which I call ESR. The voltage drop between the them determines the current and thus the power in the zener. 
 
 

Putting a Zener across a voltage source with ripple is like crowbar solution compared to a SMPS. Think again.

Pd = ΔV²/ESR  for ΔV= RMS difference V

Comment: What do you mean by a crowbar solution vs. SMPS? I am expected to have a schematic of the circuit within an hour or two and will try adding it here